# CryptographicException: The data is invalid in MVC 4 with WIF enabled

Tags: c#, security, .net-4.0, wif, windows-identity

I have created a MVC 4 Project and set it up for Azure ACS. It worked with System.Identity. I changed it to use the Microsoft.Identity for enabling WIF and my config file looks like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="microsoft.identityModel"
             type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="DefaultConnection"  />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="ACS" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <!--<authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>-->
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!--Commented out by Identity and Access VS Package-->
    <!--<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /></authentication>-->
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule"
       type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule"
           type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule"
           type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:48451/" />
      </audienceUris>

    <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <trustedIssuers>
        <add thumbprint="033F53598E4ED92E51C07238E36BBFF4E67ABAD2" name="https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net/" />
      </trustedIssuers>
    </issuerNameRegistry>

    <federatedAuthentication>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true"
                    issuer="https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation"
                    realm="http://localhost:48451/" reply="http://localhost:48451/"
                    requireHttps="false" />
    </federatedAuthentication>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>

</configuration>
```

My problem is when i run the site i get:

```
[CryptographicException: The data is invalid.
]
   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) +318
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded) +203

[InvalidOperationException: ID1073: A CryptographicException occurred when attempting to decrypt the cookie using the ProtectedData API (see inner exception for details). If you are using IIS 7.5, this could be due to the loadUserProfile setting on the Application Pool being set to false. ]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded) +319
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[] cookie, Boolean outbound) +217
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +1951
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[] token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +149
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[] sessionCookie) +598
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken) +120
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +113
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default protection in WIF is using DPAPI which fails if the profile has not been loaded (typically fails in cloud hosting). You can use MachineKey protection instead which relies on ASP.NET machine key

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/07/12/machinekey-based-session-protection-for-wif/

On the other hand if you are using NET 4.5 and System.IdentityModel that's built-in. You don't need WIF anymore and the machine key protection is available already in the core assembly. Also, you will have to reference System.IdentityModel.Services dll (which contains the http modules)

Comment: I figured it out, the issue seemed to be assosiated with the browser cache. Clearing the cache resolved the issue. Azure dont support NET 4.5 yet.

Comment: I have noticed an issue with MachineKey API when used in ASP.NET application. It fails to decrypt data after application restart. The same app has some data protected using DPAPI which works fine. I am trying to figure out what would be the cause.

Comment: @Leadfoot did you have an update on your problem after application restart?

Comment: @ActionDan I was not able to find complete cause. Perhaps MachineKey API uses less permissions since it works in medium trust unlike DPAPI. You can fix the problem by setting machine key manually in web.config(its not ideal but works). Another thing that you can try is to make sure Load user Profile is turned on your application pool.

Comment: This was a browser caching issue for me as well. Issue was rooted in that I had just closed another Visiual Studio solution I was debugging a WebAPI with. Clearing the browser cache worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't necessarily ask your visitors to clear their cookies when all they see is this exception.

My answer is to help others who have pulled their hair out due to this 'data is invalid' CryptographicException with the federated authentication. We tried lots of things and none worked except I found a mention of changing the name of the cookie because moving from WIF 3.5 to the version 4.0 it looks a like incompatible cookies may have been left behind. It's still unclear to us why. However, in our case we had two virtual application folders each with federated authentication and it looked like they may have been sharing cookies. So, we specified a unique cookie name for both the cookieHandler of each in the federated authentication, and we also specified the asp.net session cookie to have a unique name for each. If this hint helps anyone then great.